# How to check String using stack

Tags: java

I have some specific task. We have String like "(()[]<>)" or something familiar with this. A question in my interview qustion was how check either String is correct or incorrect. For example: "()[]<>" - true, "([)" - false, "[(])" - false, "([<>])" - true. Thank you guys very much!
I can' t take what's wrong with my code.
Thank a lot guys!!!
Please help!

import java.util.Stack;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line = "(<>()[])";
    Test test = new Test();
    boolean res = test.stringChecker(line);
    System.out.println(res);
}

public boolean stringChecker(String line){
    boolean result = false;
    char letter = '\u0000';
    char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == '(' || arr[i] == '[' || arr[i] == '<') {
            stack.push(arr[i]);
        }
        if(arr[i] == ')' || arr[i] == ']' || arr[i] == '>'){
                if(stack.peek() == arr[i]){
                    result = true;
                    stack.pop();

            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

(0) You are pushing < ( and { but in your peek you are checking for >, ), and }

(1) You are starting with result false and setting it to true on the first successful match. Instead you should start with result true and set it to false on the first failed match.

(2) You should check that the stack is empty when you have run out of characters.

(3) You should check for the stack being empty before you peek.

(4) You might want to check for characters that are not expected.

Comment: Thanks for your edit unfortunately I was AFK so I couldn't approve it. I've edited my answer to show the full code, feel free to improve it again!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @TheodoreNorvell 's explanation here is how an implementation could look like

```
public boolean stringChecker(String input) {
    boolean result = true;
    char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; result && i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == '(' || arr[i] == '[' || arr[i] == '<') {
                stack.push(arr[i]);
            } else if(arr[i] == ')') {
                Character c = stack.pop();
                result = c.equals('(');
            } else if(arr[i] == ']') {
                Character c = stack.pop();
                result = c.equals('[');
            } else if(arr[i] == '>') {
                Character c = stack.pop();
                result = c.equals('<');
            } else {
                // found some char that is not allowed
                // here it is not just ignored,
                // it invalidates the input  
                result = false;
            }
        }
        // when the teher is not more chars in the array
        // the stack has to be empty 
        result = result  && stack.isEmpty() ;
    } catch(EmptyStackException e) {
        // found a closing bracket in the array 
        // but there is nothing on the stack
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

@Test
public void stringChecker() {
    Assert.assertTrue(stringChecker("[]"));
    Assert.assertTrue(stringChecker("[(<>)]"));
    Assert.assertFalse(stringChecker("([<>)]"));
    Assert.assertFalse(stringChecker(">"));
    // invalid char
    Assert.assertFalse(stringChecker("<[]e>"));
    // stack is not empty
    Assert.assertFalse(stringChecker("("));
}
```

Note that in such a situation a `switch-case` statement is more elegant than `if-else if-else`.